# Can Not Login IBM Quantum Experience!

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

When I click the “IBMid”  for the first time, I can see the login page and input my username and password. However it return to the initial page(https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/login) and after that the page would give no response no matter  which button I click. What is the problem?

Comment: Are my ID or IP blocked?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not the place to report bugs on the IBM interface

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason I an think of to why they would blocked you...

I would suggest you post this issue to their support team through the [Qiskit Slack channel](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/support).

It can be problematic sometime to get connected to IBM Quantum Experience... but these issues are fixed rather quickly.